# how to enable a disabled button without javascript

Tags: forms, html, button

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap.
It has a feature for buttons, called `data-loading-text`; which will replace with `button` text when user submit the form. It also disable the button.

The problem is here: if I don't enable the button again (with javascript), and user reload the page (with `F5`), the button stays disabled....

For solve this problem, I want to rest the button when I'm printing it (with PHP), but which attribute should be deleted? Can I set `disabled="false"` for the button?? or something like that.

Any other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

ON pressing F5 page is reloaded. You need to reset all of your controls and the buttons and make

```
disabled=false
```

once loading is done.

Comment: is there any other way to detect page loading?

Comment: maybe.. (put something at the end of page before `</body>`, when it loads, page is loaded.) my question is not about detecting page loading, I want to re-enable a button without javascript. (if possible)